# Wireless Connection Failure with a Sweex Wireless 54g adapter

Tags: wireless, ralink

My internet access was fine, when I shut down my pc and then open it again! Then, the pc recognized the net's name but it does not recognize the password to the wireless!!

For some reason my mobile has access and internet settings are all good(which means that internet is fine and there's something wrong with the computer)!

It still connects with an ethernet but cannot connect wireless! I desperately need some help here!

Comment: Can you provide the wireless card you are using and the version of Ubuntu you are using.

Comment: Of course! The version of Ubuntu is 11.10! As for the wireless, I use a usb: wireless 54G adapter(sweex)... If there's anything you can do, I would really appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Can you plug into the ethernet and then try this and then update your question with what happens? http://askubuntu.com/questions/47506/how-do-i-install-a-graphics-or-wireless-card-driver

Answer (score 1):

Click on the wireless icon at the top, then click "Connect to hidden wireless" and fill in the required fields. I hope it helps.